# Java - How to store most recent strings from input stream?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, inputstream

I have an input stream which provides me with a new string every 1 second. I want to store the 25 most recent strings to access at any time. I'm working in Java and do not want to use anything outside of the common library. I would prefer to create a separate class for this implementation.

As an example:

```
String a = "string a";
String b = "string b";
String c = "string c";
...

storedStrings[0] = c;
storedStrings[1] = b;
storedStrings[2] = a;
```

when String d = "string d" arrives I want storedStrings to shift like so:

```
storedStrings[0] = d;
storedStrings[1] = c;
storedStrings[2] = b;
storedStrings[3] = a;
```

and after I've loaded 25 strings in, I no longer care about the value of String a and it should be discarded so as not to take up memory. I've tried ArrayList and am not having success. Is this a use case for Vector?

Point me in the right direction, please!

### Updating with my implemented solution, using LinkedList:

```
public static void addToQueue(String s){
         if (list == null) list = new LinkedList<>();
           list.addFirst(s);
           System.out.println(s);
           if (list.size() > 25) {
           list.removeLast();
           }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done very easily with linked list :

```
   LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
   list.addFirst("your new string");
   list.removeLast();
```

Or just with anything that extends List by following (this will work for ArrayList as well) :

```
   List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
   list.add(0,"your new string");
   list.remove(list.size()-1);
```

Or you can use Queue

```
    Queue<String> que = new LinkedList<>();
    que.add("your new string");
    que.remove();
```

Comment: You should check for size in your examples.  Only remove if the list/queue size become greater than 25

Comment: Well filling it was not the problem for questions author, he wanted to know what to do after... So I made several examples as simple as possible for easy reading.

Comment: A lot of very helpful answers! Thanks, libik for the LinkedList suggestion. It was an effective and simple implementation.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

1. Check the size
2. If it's smaller than the maximum, enqueue, if it is at the maximum, dequeue, then enqueue the next element
3. ???
4. Profit

Answer (score 1):

You can use arraylist.add(0,element). This will add a new element to the first position and shift all elements of the list one spot to the right. If you already have 25 elements then you would simply remove the last element.

```
    if(ArrayList.size()>=25){
        ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.size()-1);
    }
    ArrayList.add(0,d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a LinkedList

```
LinkedList<String> array = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    array.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
array.removeFirst();
for (String s : array) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Using queues:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractQueue<String> array = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(25);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {          
        if (array.size() >= 25)
            array.remove();
        array.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    for (String s : array) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```